# Playing *.avi files with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, video, codec, avi

I am trying to play *.avi file (~900MB) with this code:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("mes1.avi"));
player->setVideoOutput(ui->videoWidget);
player->play();
```

where `ui->videoWidget` is `QVideoWidget` and every time I play it I am getting this error code (in Application Output console)

Since google doesn't help, this is my only choice...

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)
```

**EDIT1:**
I have installed K-Lite Codec Pack 12.2.6.

**EDIT2:**
My application is 32bit, but it shouldn't be a problem since K-Lite include 32bit ([source](https://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)).

Comment: I googled the error and found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287688/qt5-video-render-error-code-80040218. You need to install codecs on your computer

Comment: You can try vlc-qt

Comment: @sashoalm I've already installed K-Lite Codec Pack 12.2.6 and it didn't do much...

Comment: @Zen could you tell me what that is, I am not sure.

Comment: [VLC-Qt - a simple library to connect Qt application with libVLC](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt). Its usage is very easy. And you don't need to worry about codecs anymore.

Comment: It sounds nice, but I wouldn't really like to use an extra library if I can do it only with Qt.

Comment: Have you tried other formats? Like .mp4 oder .mkv?

Comment: @Felix Yes, I have no problem with two that you have mentioned.

Comment: Well, in that case the codec itself works, it's just avi... maybe your video file is corrupted? Or your installation of the codec?

Comment: @Felix I've just installed K-Lite Mega and Update (removed previous version) and still same issue... Video is fine since I am able to play it even in Windows Media Player...

Comment: @Zen I've ended up using your solution because it seems that it's the only solution. If you want answer a question so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use vlc-qt, and you will find it is so easy to play all sorts of video on all platforms, even XP, which has been abandoned by qt long time ago.