# Deployed video application cannot play avi files

Tags: qt

I made a qt video player application. When I run the application from Qt Creator, it can play avi files, but when I run the deployed binary executable, it cannot play avi files. However it can play mp4 files. What is missing for the executable? Is it a dll or something? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: "cannot play" is not a problem description. Does it crash? Does it give any message? Does it log any output to the terminal or some relevant log file? How does the code try to play the AVI file?

Comment: Probably there is a missing codec.

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572619/playing-avi-files-with-qt

Comment: If you use `Windows 10` you can install `LAVFilters` to codec your media.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. It is because of a missing plugin I forgot to include with the binary executable.